# Prove that there's no ordered basis $E$ in which $T{x\choose y}={0\choose y}$ can be represented as $1\ 2\choose 2\ 4$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that:

$$T\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ y\end{pmatrix}$$

Show that there's no ordered-basis, $E$ such that:

$$[T]_E = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 2\\
   2 & 4\\ 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

I didn't get how should I prove it. I tried some ways but end up with nothing. I guess I'm missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trace is unvariant under change of basis. In the canonical basis, $T$ has for matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and then $\mathrm{trace}T = 1$. The second matrix has trace $5 \neq 1$. Therefore, there is no basis in wich this is the matrix of $T$.

Comment: very nice! I was thinking of considering eigenvalues ($T$ has eigenvalues $0,1$, as is easily computed in standard basis, but the given matrix has eigenvalues $0,5$)... but your approach is much easier.

Comment: Trace is the most simple invariant for matrices, so try it first before computing eigenvalues which is a really difficult problem in dimension $\geqslant 5$

Comment: @DIdier_ I noticed the trace too, unfortunately I can't use it for this proof. Do you see any other way? I tried to do something with the columns vectors but got nothing

Comment: Your two matrices have the same rank 1, thus the same determinant. I don't see a simpler proof than the trace to prove these matrices are not similar, sorry

Answer (score 3):

With

$T \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ y \end{pmatrix}, \tag 1$

we have

$T \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \tag 2$

and

$T \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \tag 3$

which shows the eigenvalues of $T$ are $0$ and $1$; on the other hand, the eigevalues of the matrix

$[T]_E = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \tag 4$

are the roots of its characteristic polynomial

$\det ([T]_E - \lambda I) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 - \lambda & 2 \\ 2 & 4 - \lambda \end{pmatrix}$
$= (1 - \lambda)(4 - \lambda) - 4 = 4 - 5\lambda + \lambda^2 - 4 = \lambda^2 - 5 \lambda, \tag 5$

which are $0$ and $5$; since the eigenvalues of the transformation $T$ as in (1) are $0$ and $1$, it cannot be represented by (4) in any basis $E$.