# find an ordered basis ot prove it doesn't exist

Tags: linear-transformations

[image]

if we say B =(b1,b2) , b1 = [x1,y1] , b2=[x2,y2]
so [T(b1)]B = (1,2) ===> 1*b1 +2*b2 = [0,y1]
and [T(b2)]B = (2,4) ===> 2*b1 +4*b2 = [0,y2]
how can I go from there ?

Comment: Please take the time to learn the basics of MathJax. You've been a member for nearly a month ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that there's no ordered basis $E$ in which $T{x\choose y}={0\choose y}$ can be represented as $1\ 2\choose 2\ 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682829/prove-that-theres-no-ordered-basis-e-in-which-tx-choose-y-0-choose-y-ca)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such basis. The trace of the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to a basis does not depend upon the basis. And tthe matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, whose trace is $1$. But $\operatorname{tr}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{smallmatrix}\right]=5$.